# get process start time in kernel module solaris

Tags: c, time, solaris, unix-timestamp, high-resolution-clock

I am trying to get process start time in kernel module.
I get the [proc struct pointer](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/proc.h#139), and from the proc I take field p_mstart ()

```
typedef struct  proc {
.....
/*
* Microstate accounting, resource usage, and real-time profiling
*/
hrtime_t p_mstart;      /* hi-res process start time */
```

this return me the number: 1976026375725303

```
struct proc* iterated_process_ptr = curproc
LOG("***KERNEL***: PID=%d, StartTime=%lld",iterated_process_ptr->p_pidp->pid_id, iterated_process_ptr->p_mstart);
```

What is this number ? 
In the documentation solaris write:

```
The gethrtime() function returns the current high-resolution real time. Time is expressed as nanoseconds since some arbitrary time in the past.
```

And in the book Solaris Internals they write:

```
Within the process, the operating system maintains a high-resolution teimstamp that marks process start and terminate times, A p_mstart field, the process start time, is set in the kernel fork() code when the process is created.... it return 64-bit value expressed in nanosecond
```

The number 1976026375725303 does not make sense at all.
If i divide by 1,000,000,000 and then by 3600 in order to get hours, i get 528 hours, 22 days, but my uptime is 5 days..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on answer received at google group: comp.unix.solaris.

Instead of going to proc -> p_mstart

I need to take

```
iterated_process_ptr ->p_user.u_start
```

This bring me the same struct (timestruc_t) as userspace

```
typedef struct psinfo {  

psinfo ->pr_start;  /* process start time, from the epoch */
```

Answer (score 1):

*The number 1976026375725303 does not make sense at all.*

Yes it does.  Per the very documentation that you quoted:

> Time is expressed as nanoseconds since some arbitrary time in the
>   past.

Thus, the value can be used to calculate how long ago the process started:

```
hrtime_t howLongAgo = gethrtime() - p->p_mstart;
```

That produces a value in nanoseconds for how long ago the process started.

And note that the value produced is accurate - the value from `iterated_process_ptr ->p_user.u_start` is subject to system clock changes, so you can't say, "This process has been running for 3 hours, 15 minutes, and 3 seconds" unless you also know the system clock hasn't been reset or modified in any way.

Per the [Solaris 11 gethrtime.9F man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1477/gethrtime-9f.html#scrolltoc):

> **Description**
>
> The `gethrtime()` function returns the current high-resolution real
>   time. **Time is expressed as nanoseconds since some arbitrary time in
>   the past; it is not correlated in any way to the time of day**, and
>   thus is not subject to resetting or drifting by way of `adjtime(2)` or
>   `settimeofday(3C)`. The hi-res timer is ideally suited to performance
>   measurement tasks, where cheap, accurate interval timing is required.
>
> **Return Values**
>
> `gethrtime()` always returns the current high-resolution real time.
>   There are no error conditions.
>
> ...
>
> **Notes**
>
> Although the units of hi-res time are always the same (nanoseconds),
>   the actual resolution is hardware dependent. Hi-res time is guaranteed
>   to be monotonic (it does not go backward, it does not periodically
>   wrap) and linear (it does not occasionally speed up or slow down for
>   adjustment, as the time of day can), but not necessarily unique: two
>   sufficiently proximate calls might return the same value.
>
> The time base used for this function is the same as that for
>   `gethrtime(3C)`. Values returned by both of these functions can be
>   interleaved for comparison purposes.

Comment: Thanks, i am not measuring the life of the process, I send a list of processes from kernel to user, and for each process i do something, if the process died, i dont want to do something for the wrong process.. maybe a new process came to life with the exact pid.. so i save the processId+StartTime, this is best way to make sure i am talking about the same process. And from userspace i didnt find the way to get high-res time for a given process id (integer is the ID)

Comment: @ilansch *And from userspace i didnt find the way to get high-res time for a given process id (integer is the ID)*  It may not be accessible from user space. Not a big deal, but from within kernel space, pid and `p_mstart` should be just about guaranteed to be unique.  I don't see any way for process IDs to roll over fast enough to get the same value for `p_mstart` for two processes with identical PIDs. The first one would have to start, run, and die, then the process ids would have to roll over, and a new process get started with the same PID, all before `gethrtime()` rolls to the next value.

Comment: Hi, thats the point, there is *no way* that 2 processes will have identical PID and start time, but there could be 2 processes with the same PID (one will die and new one will take place).... thats why i need the PID+Starttime when marking my processes